# JSPM : importing SCSS with SystemJS in Angular2/TypeScript project doesn't works

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sass, systemjs

### Context

I'm working on a project using Angular2, TS and SystemJS. I've built a simple module loader using SystemJS which allows me to import 'custom' modules like this :

`import { NavComponent } from "component@nav";`

Maybe it'll be important.

### Goal

I would like to import `.scss` files inside my angular components to be able to do things like that :

```
@Component({ 
    selector: 'app-view',
    styles: [ require('path/to/mainScss/file.scss') ],
    template: //...
})
```

### Issue

I've found some examples using webpack but I can't get this works. During searching, I've found [this module](https://github.com/mobilexag/plugin-sass). It can be interesting because it uses SystemJS like me and I don't have to add webpack to my project.

So I've decided to use it (and I'm not sure if it's possible to use webpack and SystemJS at the same time. `require` was undefined). I didn't know jspm before using this module, I've always used npm. So I've installed jspm locally (relative to my project) and globally and I've installed the module.

Then, inside a component : `import './styles/importer.scss!';`. And I get an error here.

**`Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`**. I know that this error happens when SystemJS failed to load a module but I can't figure out why.

### Why ?!

Why am I trying to do that ?

My module loader allows me to write some modules in separate folders (named like this `namepace@name`). I can add those folders inside another one named `modules/` and then enable/disable modules by editing a configuration file.

So I want my `.scss` files to be loaded only if a module is enabled. That's why I want to include my sass inside an Angular component. That way, it'll be loaded only if the component is loaded.

Comment: That is **not** an answer to this issue. I've found another way to use my `scss` files. For more information, see [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36552326/5542588)