# Angular 2: is styleUrls relative to the current component?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, angular

I'm encounter some troubles to add style to my angular 2 component using `styleUrls`.

Here is how I use it :

**path/main.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-view',
    styleUrls: ['./styles/style.css'],
    template: //...
})
```

**path/styles/style.css**

```
.main-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red; }
```

And nothing happens in my browser. 
I've tried with :

- an absolute path
- a path relative to the root component.

I've also tried :

- to write this with different syntaxes like `'./styles/style.css'`, `'styles/style.css'`
- to move my `style.css` next to my component.

But I can't get it works.

Comment: Quoting official documentation: `The URL is relative to the application root which is usually the location of the index.html web page that hosts the application. The style file URL is not relative to the component file. That's why the example URL begins app/. See Appendix 2 to specify a URL relative to the component file` (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#loading-style).

Comment: Haha. I completely forgot the official doc. Shame on me, thanks. I leave this answer here in case other people doesn't read the doc :).

Comment: If you add `moduleId: module.id` to the component decorator, the URLs become relative.

Comment: `module` is provided by setting the `ts.config`'s `module` to **commonjs**. Unfortunately I'm using **SytemJS** and I've built a 'module loader' with SystemJS so I can't switch to commonjs

Comment: use '__moduleName' instead of module.id if you are using SystemJS

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `styleUrls`. Simply rename the style file with `scss` extension. The stylesheet will be used automatically!

Therefore, my component's files will be like this, and will work with the style:

- mycomponent.ts
- mycomponent.html
- mycomponent.scss